# how do I get individual elements of functions in a list and put them in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, coefficients

Edit: Included a sample result

I created functions like so:

```
Ex1 = function(a,b,c) 1 * a + 2 * b + 3 * c + 4
Ex2 = function(a,b,c)
Ex3 = function(a,b,c)
etc..
```

and put them in a list:

```
exList = list(Ex1,Ex2,Ex3,etc.)
```

now I have to use a function to get the individual elements ([a,b,c] and the numbers (separately))

I'm having trouble there for the most part, having tried substring and split to no avail (or I'm just not using it properly), since I do know how to create a matrix.

An example of the result would be:

```
   a  b  c RHS
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
3  9 10 11  12
```

But long story short, I need to create an **Augmented Coefficient Matrix**.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Am I understanding correctly that you need to extract `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` from, e.g., `Ex1`? Why are you creating these functions this way if you need to extract these values later on? Instead of coding a complicated way for extracting the numbers from function bodies, you should fix the preceding steps.

Comment: As @Roland says I think you need to step back and consider what you are trying to do and whether you are using functions appropriately. [Here's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_functions.htm) some information about building functions in R.

Comment: @Roland yes, I need to extract the numbers from said function(s).

The examples I provided were supposed to be entered in the console, which is why I had it written that way. And they had to be added to a list before calling the function that is supposed to create the matrix from the given functions.

But still, thanks for helping out to you and

Comment: @JosephCrispell thanks as well for giving a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the numbers like this:

```
Ex1 <- function(a,b,c) 1 * a + 2 * b + 3 * c + 4


foo <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) > 1) {
    res <- lapply(x, foo)
  } else {
      res <- if(is.numeric(x)) x else NA
  }
  na.omit(unlist(res))
}

foo(body(Ex1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

However, I strongly encourage you to change your whole approach. It could be something like this:

```
coefs <- list(c1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), c2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8))
callerFun <- function(a, b, c, coefs) c(cbind(a, b, c, 1) %*% coefs)

#example use
a <- 1:2
b <- 3:4
c <- 5:6

lapply(coefs, callerFun, a = a, b = b, c = c)
#$c1
#[1] 26 32
#
#$c2
#[1] 66 84
```

Comment: I have a late question, if I can still ask. Is there a way to get the negative symbol on numbers on it as well? For example, I have [1,2,3,4] from the function, but 3 is -3 from the original. Is it possible to run a second copy of the function to make it negative or is there a function that allows me to do it? Thanks. @Roland

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I'm amazed that you are still following that convoluted path instead of just fixing your overall approach.

Comment: Btw., I have the distinct impression that computing on the language by recursively crawling the call tree is beyond your current skill level. I really don't think you do yourself a favor by doing this. You probably don't understand how it works and won't be able to maintain it. I can easily do what you are asking but I wouldn't in my own code. It's just a bad approach.