# How to get and properly identify a function stored in a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, variables, numbers

I need to be able to add functions in a list and be able to call it using a `for()` function.

Example:

```
Sample1 = function(a,c,b) c*3 + b*2 + a*1 +  3
Sample2 = function(d,e,f) d*1 + e*2 + f*3 + 5

sampleRList = list(Sample1,Sample2)
```

When I call

```
for(item in sampleRList){
   print(typeof(item))
}
```

it prints out `closure` like normal since it is a function, but when I try to get the variables in the function using

```
foo <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) > 1) {
    res <- lapply(x, foo)
  } else {
      res <- if(is.numeric(x)) x else NA
  }
  na.omit(unlist(res))
}

foo(body(item))
```

^(sample code) where x would be the current item, it does not return the list containing the variables/numbers.

example of expected result is
`[1] 1 2 3 4`

How do I fix this? Thanks.

`foo` code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65003838/how-do-i-get-individual-elements-of-functions-in-a-list-and-put-them-in-a-matrix) <<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not terribly clear what you are asking here. I *think* you are saying that you want to extract the multiplicative coefficients from the functions `Sample1` and `Sample2` using the function `foo`, but you need to be able to do it if `Sample1` and `Sample2` are in a list.

In your example, you call `foo(body(Ex1))`, but you have no object called `Ex1`, so this code throws an error. If on the other hand you call:

```r
foo(body(sampleRList[[1]]))
#> [1] 3 2 1 3
```

Then you can see that you retrieve the correct coefficients from `Sample1`, and to retrieve those from `Sample2` you would do:

```r
foo(body(sampleRList[[2]]))
#> [1] 1 2 3 5
```

If you wanted to get both at the same time you could do:

```r
lapply(sampleRList, function(x) foo(body(x)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 3 2 1 3
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 5
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ```Ex1``` problem. I more or less just copied the code from the answer there. I'll be back for the result of the code testing. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for replying back this late. It worked perfectly. Thanks!